# GIMP 2.10 disable view rotation

Tags: shortcut-keys, gimp

I'm a heavy blender user, and I'm used to shift+mmb being used for panning. However in GIMP that results in image view being rotated, which is very annoying, since you have to manually go through the menus every time (**View** > **Flip and Rotate** > **Reset Flip and Rotate**). Sure it has a shortcut (exclamation mark), but it's still annoying. I tried changing this keyboard shortcut or maybe even disable it, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the shortcut editor.

Is there even a way to disable this or am I stuck with resetting the view forever?

Comment: I hate this with every bone in my body.... Inkscape as well!!

Answer (score 0):

I too am frustrated with this and have not found a way to truly disable, though I know of a quicker way to reset. Instead of going to view you can go to the bottom of the screen beside your scale % and there is a xx.xx° which can be clicked and you can click reset or what I do, 0 then Enter on numpad (a bit quicker for me)

Comment: Just pressing exclamation mark (!) resets it too.